# Whats the best practice for the number of items an enum should contain?

Tags: c#, enums

I'm working on a project that implements the factory pattern. The factory uses an enum for the switch statement.

The values in the enum correspond to id's in a database table. The number of items in the table has > 30 items and is growing. The table should not grow to more than about 100 items.

Should i be using an enum in the case? What are my alternatives?

Comment: does "no more than you need and no less than you need" cover most scenarios?

Comment: Well, all your enums must have exactly 42 values.

Comment: Not sure why im getting down voted, just wanted some advice - i thought there were no stupid questions. So your saying an enum with 100 values is considered ok?

Comment: Thanks for your response Marc. Yes, indeed, it does cover most scenarios. I was hoping for something a little more helpful though. I'm here to learn and hopefully become a better developer, these kinds of responses are discouraging to say the least.

Comment: There is no really best practices for that - it is *your* code and you will need to read it. If you like code when you read it - than it is ok to have many elements. Any suggestion would be personal choice (i.e. under 10 for me) - so I don't think it is really good question for SO as it stands now.

Answer (score 1):

The number of enum members with distinct values is limited by the underlying type of enum (Int32 by default). Anyway... with an Int32 enum you can have up to 2^32 distinct values. Example:

```
public enum MyEnum : byte { /* 256 Distinct Members */ }
```

But you can have as many members as you want provided they all have the same value:

```
public enum MyEnum : byte { A, B = A, C = B, ... }
```

There is probably some implementation-defined limit in C# compiler, but I would expect it to be memory dependent.

Comment: That's really not the question.

Answer (score 0):

It would become a rather long switch statement but there is nothing wrong per se with using 100 elements in an enum, and it would be rather fast.

The alternative might be to populate a `Dictionary<int, Func<TFactoryResult>>`, but without knowing a bit more about your factory implementation it is difficult to give advice. The enum will most likely always be the fastest choice, but not provide the most readable code.